# Corrections to energy levels in many-electron atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, spectroscopy, atoms

While I've been solving the Hydrogen atom problem, using quantum mechanics, I came across several correction factors, that give rise to the fine structure of the hydrogen spectrum.

The Hamiltonian can be written as :

$$H = H_{non-rel} + H_{rel} +H_{S-O} $$

As one can see, the first term is the standard non-relativistic hamiltonian that gives rise to Bohr's energy levels. The final two terms give rise to the fine structure energy levels. The second term is the relativistic term and the final one is the spin-orbit coupling term. These are treated as perturbations.

However, this is quite different from many-electron atoms. Over there, we use the central field approximation that involves the electrostatic repulsion, the original hamiltonian, and the spin-orbit interaction.

We have :

$$H = H_{central-field} + H_{S-O}$$

The problem here is, the central field hamiltonian includes the non-relativistic hamiltonian and the electrostatic repulsion. However, it doesn't involve the relativistic correction to the kinetic energy as we did in the hydrogen atom.

Why do we ignore the relativistic and Darwin correction terms in the central field approximation in many-electron atoms, or are these terms already included?
If not, how do we add those corrections to the hamiltonian, and why do most books ignore those ? The relativistic correction should be bigger than the spin-orbit correction I suppose. Why do we involve it in hydrogen atoms, but not for others, like sodium atoms for example.

Moreover, the energy of alkalis, neglecting the spin orbit coupling is given by the following :

$$E = \frac{-R_H}{[n-\delta(l)]^2}$$

This is an empirical formula, and $\delta(l)$ represents quantum defects. This equation manages to give us the energy levels of different configurations, till the fine structure level. However, this is an empirical formula. But we often calculate energy levels using this, and then add the spin-orbit term to it, to get the fine-structure levels.

Is the following, safe to say :

$$\langle H_{cental-field}\rangle = \frac{-R_H}{[n-\delta(l)]^2}$$

I don't know if this is correct, as the central field expectation value is calculated numerically, and the formula to the right is just an empirical modification of the Rydberg formula. However, since they both give the same result, maybe we can derive the formula to the right, from the central field approximation? Can anyone clear this for me ?

These are my two questions: Why do we ignore relativistic correction in many-electron energy levels ? Is the empirical formula related to the central-field approximation ?

Comment: Mean field approximation gives much larger error than lack of relativistic corrections.